# while and if condition within a case statement t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to implement a while loop and if condition (with a function call) in a case statement. Basically, I am trying to do this:

```
begin
    case
       when (condition1 and condition 2 and ncolumn_num between 6 and 9) 
          then
             while @i < 10
             begin
                 if(hsip.Is_numeric( hsip.getTempResponseById(@cregion, @cState_code, @nFY, @nReport_id, @nsection_id, @nquestion_number, @ndisplay_number, @nquestion_number, @nquestion_part_number, @suser_id, @nrow_number, i, @suser_id)))

@nrunningtotal = @nrunningtotal + hsip.getTempResponseById(@cRegion, @cState_code, @nFY, @nReport_id, @nsection_id, @nquestion_number, @ndisplay_number, @nquestion_number,
    @nquestion_part_number, @suser_id, @nrow_number, @ncolumn_number, @suser_id)

        end if
end
```

Can I implement while loop and if condition within case statement. My business logic requires me to total the columns from 6 to 9 and have final total in col:10.

I have 2 functions: `gettempresponsebyid`: which returns response string and `isnumeric` function which converts to number.

Can someone please suggest a better way of doing this. I get this error:

> INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR IF AND INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR RUNNINGTOTAL.

Comment: Can you provide ddl, input data and expected output? Looks like we donot require to do while loop

Comment: This is not what the `CASE` *expression* is for.  Please share some sample data and desired results.  It sounds like you're going about the problem all wrong (read: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378))

Comment: You are thinking of data processing as you would in a conventional programming language - iteratively. SQL has a different paradigm, its primary use does not include iterating. You can iterate in TSQL extension, but that is secondary to SQL. You get running totals by using the window functions most of the time these days.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an ***EXPRESSION*** that evaluates into one (of several possible) atomic values - it is ***NOT*** a **statement** to control the flow of execution in your code - use `IF / THEN / ELSE` for that....

Answer (score 4):

Q: Can I implement while loop and if condition within case statement.

A: No. `CASE` is not a T-SQL *statement*. It's an *expression*.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

In the posted code, one big syntax problem starts right here:

```
BEGIN CASE ...
      ^
```

Use the `IF / ELSE` statement to conditionally control flow in T-SQL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

For a start, replace the invalid usage of the `CASE` expression with an `IF` statement.

```
BEGIN
  IF (condition1 AND condition2 AND ncolumn_num between 6 and 9)
    BEGIN
      ...
    END;
  END IF;
END;
```

But even with that change, it's still not clear what you are attempting to achieve or what problem you are trying to solve. There is likely a much better way to do what you are trying to do, but we'd just be throwing out guesses at what you are trying to do.

Comment: The expected output for this procedure is runningtotal which would be runningtotal= runningtotal+numericof(response_string), the response string is the output of the "gettempresponsebyid" function. So, if the user accidentally enters anything other than a numeric value then it returns 0 and calculates the running total. Then, this runningtotal output has to be stored in total_correct column (col 6 though 9=colno. 10). 
I am stuck and not sure which approach to follow. Can you please suggest a workaround for this. I can post the pseudo code if you like. thanks